# PowerPivot - Your beta software has expired

Tags: microsoft-excel, powerpivot

I'm running the 32-bit version of Excel 2010 on Windows 7 64. I've downloaded the 32-bit version of PowerPivot from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/bi/en-us/solutions/pages/powerpivot.aspx) however I get the following error:

[image]

Now I can see what the error message is telling me but I've downloaded the latest version. I've also done a google search and a few hits turned up in 2010 with similiar issues when running older versions of the software but the replies tend to point the user to downloading the latest version of PowerPivot. I have done that as of 15th December 2011.

Does anyone have any ideas what the issue may be here?

Comment: Any way of using 64-bit Excel 2010 instead of 32-bit?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue with x64 PowerPivot in x64 Excel on x64 Windows 7.